# Как убрать обязательный ввод пароля при регистрации пользователя в WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я хочу заменить стандартную страницу регистрациина сайте (/wp-login.php) на страницу регистрации в аккаунте woocommerce (/my-account/). Мне нужна реализация именно этим способом - регистрация должна быть на отдельной странице.

При этом в стандартной регистрации у меня всего два обязательных поля - имя и email, а в регистрации woocommerce еще обязательное поле - пароль. Я хочу убрать обязательный ввод пароля в регистраии woocommerce. Как это сделать?

Comment: В вуке обязательный пароль нужен для того, чтобы затем залогинить пользователя в систему, а в вордпресс отправляется пароль на почту и там уже через почту можно зайти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Админка -> /woocommerce/Учетки и приватность/ - поставить галку на "При создании учётной записи автоматически создавать пароль для неё."

Я искал решение через хуки, а оказалось все решается через админку.